# How to change datatypes while reading excel sheet using OLEDB

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am trying to convert value string to number in OLEDB select query but am getting below error

**Undefined function 'DT_NUMERIC' in expression.**

am trying with below query

```
SELECT DT_NUMERIC(PhoneNumber,0) From [$sheet1]
```

Actually value is coming like 8.90141E+19 but i want to convert it to like this 89014103244078900000

Please suggest your thoughts.

Comment: why don't you add it in temp table or object and perform your operation in that object.

Comment: yes you are correct actually the problem is value is coming like this (8.90141E+19)

Comment: ok, that makes sense, so it would be easy to convert it from object instead of direct sheet.

Comment: i am not getting your point can you elaborate plz...